# Is it possible to integrate spring mvc ,hibernate apllication with solr?

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, solr, integration

How can I integrate Spring Hibernate application with `solr`?

Can anyone please provide me sample working examples?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, Spring has one specific project in the Spring Data projects tree.
http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-solr/

You can take a look to ElasticSearch too.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch

Comment: hi dani                                                                                                         in myapplication iam using spring mvc with hibernate and i want to integrate solr also.i just want both hibernate and solr together.

Comment: You should think in one good way to develop your software architecture, what objects do you want to put in solr?, when?, why?. In you business layer methods, for example, if the objects don't exist in Solr, get them from db with Hibernate and set them into sorl. Maybe this link can help you. http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-solr-tutorial/